# Three.js - Issue loading Blender model

Tags: three.js, blender

I want to import a blender model into three.js, but I havent been successful yet.

This is what I have:

```
  <script src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>

// CHILDREN  
                children = new THREE.Object3D();

// Blender Model
                var bld = (blend[4]).toString();
                var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
                loader.load(bld,handle_load);
                var mesh;
                console.log(bld); // "/media/accounts/2878836292/2878836292.glb"

                function handle_load(gltf) {
                    mesh = gltf.scene.children[0];
                    mesh.position.set(-50, 15, -50);
                    children.add(mesh);

                    // mesh.position.z = -10;
                }
 //cylinder
                image = (images[0]).toString();
                const texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image);
                const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture1 });

                geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 20, 40, 20);
                var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1);
                cylinder.position.set(-90, 20, 30);
                children.add(cylinder);
```

Blender Model: https://workupload.com/file/AEm5FgER

I don't get any errors in the web console.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please share the `glb` file in this thread?

Comment: I've imported the asset in the following three.js based [gltf-viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) and the babylon.js sandbox https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/. No problems with loading the file. Try to add some lights to your scene and see if it helps.

Comment: Ive updated my post

Comment: Solved it. I had to scale the model up to 15mm to make it visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I had to scale the model up to 15mm to make it visible